# Cannot add foreign key constraints, Mysql Error 1215

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Please could you please tell me what I am doing wrong with my foreign keys? I have MySQl script but finally, during creating Authorizations table I got this:

```
Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraints
```

Here is code of my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProfilePublicData
(
    idProfile INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    login VARCHAR(64),
    name VARCHAR(45),
    lastName VARCHAR(45),
    location VARCHAR(45),
    age TINYINT,
    photo VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY(idProfile)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProfilePrivateData
(
    idProfile INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkIdProfile 
            FOREIGN KEY(idProfile) 
            REFERENCES `ProfilePublicData`(idProfile)
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    email VARCHAR(45),
    password VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY(idProfile)
);
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Authorizations
(
    idAuthorization INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkPrivateDataProfile
            FOREIGN KEY(email) 
            REFERENCES `ProfilePrivateData`(email)            
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
     systemStatus ENUM ('ONLINE','OFFLINE','DELETED'),
    `dateTimeStart` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `dateTimeRequest` DATETIME
);
```

Comment: Can you create the first 2 tables successfully?

Comment: Yes, first 2 tables are successfully created

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the email, as the email is not part of the primary key, try to remove the email and test the code again.
this part I mean:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Authorizations
(
    idAuthorization INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkPrivateDataProfile
            FOREIGN KEY(email) 
            REFERENCES `ProfilePrivateData`(email)            
                ON DELETE CASCADE 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
     systemStatus ENUM ('ONLINE','OFFLINE','DELETED'),
    `dateTimeStart` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `dateTimeRequest` DATETIME
);
```